# Question regarding the time (in)dependence of uncertainty/expectation values of position and location in Quantum Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I am trying to work out the time (in)dependence of uncertainty/expectation values of position and location in Quantum Mechanics. Let's take a simple example: a particle with mass m that moves one-dimensionally in potential $V(x)$ and is described at a certain time (say $t=0$) by the following wave function:

$$
\psi(x,t_0)=Ne^{-\frac{x^2}{2t_0^2}}
$$
where N and l are positive constants.

Now say that we know this function changes with time, but we have no idea how it does so (literally any time-dependent element could be added by multiplication in order to obtain the full expression). Can the uncertainty of position and uncertainty of momentum be time-dependent?

Whenever I try textbook examples, the time-dependent expression is always some complex exponent $e^{-i…}$, and then evidently the time-dependence disappears while integrating; but I am trying to figure out whether this is part of some greater rule that always holds true. If so, what is the logic behind it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you just tried starting with the simplest case of a free particle? For a gaussian profile for instance, N is not constant in time (the wave function spreads out as it moves). The full solution includes a real exponential that is time dependent along with the imaginary exponential.

Comment: thank you Triatticus! And I assume that leaves the uncertainty of position and momentum as time-dependent, right?

Comment: In the free-particle case, the uncertainty in momentum is independent of time. This is because the momentum eigenstates are states of definite energy as well.

Answer (score 1):

The uncertainty relations are derivated from the operator commutation rules at the same time instant, so they hold with the time evolution. On the other hand, the actual uncertainty of each of the quantities may evolve. While the evolution operator is the general way to represent time evolution, one can easily evolve the wave function in the OP by expanding it in terms of plane waves, which are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with known time evolution:
$$
\phi_k(x,t)=e^{ikx-i\omega_k t}, \omega_k=\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m},\\
\psi(x,t)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\tilde{\psi}(k)\phi_k(x,t),\\
\tilde{\psi}(k) = \int dx\psi(x,t_0)\phi_k(x,t_0)^*.
$$
(I might be sloppy with the math here, since I am writing this on the fly.)